# ¿Cómo cambiar el nombre de los valores y los títulos de la tabla generada por dfsummary() en Rmarkdown?

Tags: r-markdown

Tengo un dataframe sobre el cual deseo hacer un análisis descriptivo y presentarlo en un documento.

Para ello, empleo la librería `summarytools`

El código es el siguiente (en Rmarkdown):

```
library(readxl)
datos_def <- read_excel("datos_def_excel")

datos_modelo <- subset(datos_def, select = c("SAP", "sexo", "edad"))
                       
datos_modelo$SAP <- factor(datos_modelo$SAP,labels = c("Buena salud","Mala salud"))
datos_modelo$sexo <- factor(datos_modelo$sexo,labels = c("Mujer","Hombre"))

library(summarytools)
view(dfSummary(datos_modelo)) # genera la tabla en formato html
```

y la tabla generada es la siguiente:

[image: tabla generada]

Básicamente quiero que todas las palabras que estén en inglés pasarlas a español. Entiendo que de poder hacerse, debería ir cambiando manualmente palabra por palabra. Me explico:

Por ejemplo:

- En la columna de Stats/Values de la variable edad quiero cambiar la palabra "Mean" por "Media"
- El título de la columna "Graph" cambiarlo por "Gráfico"
- "Distinc values" por "Valores distintos"
- "[Numeric]" por "[Numérico]"

Los títulos de las columnas no me preocupan tanto, ya que puedo pasar el archivo generado de html a docx y cambiarlo desde el Word. Pero como tengo muchas más variables que las que aparecen en esta pregunta, sería mucho más factible poder cambiarlas desde Rstudio, sobretodo me interesa cambiar las palabras de las columnas Stats/Values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Traducciones en summarytools

En la documentación del paquete [12.2 Definir y Usar Traducciones Personalizadas (está en inglés)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/summarytools/vignettes/Introduction.html)
se puede usar la función ...

```
use_custom_lang()
```

... para personalizar el idioma. Dentro de esta función hay que agregar la ruta completa donde se encuentra la respectiva [plantilla en csv](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dcomtois/summarytools/master/translations/language_template.csv), descárgala y edita la columna `custom`. La implementación quedaría así:

```
datos_def <- read.csv(file="tu_ruta_aqui/datos_de_csv.csv")
datos_modelo <- subset(datos_def, select = c("SAP", "sexo", "edad"))
datos_modelo

datos_modelo$SAP <- factor(datos_modelo$SAP,labels = c("Buena salud","Mala salud"))
datos_modelo$sexo <- factor(datos_modelo$sexo,labels = c("Mujer","Hombre"))

library(summarytools)
use_custom_lang("tu_ruta_aqui/language_template.csv")
dfs <- dfSummary(datos_modelo)
vdfs <- view(dfs, footnote = NA) # Puedes desabilitar el pie de pagina si lo deseas
```

## Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El pie de página lo puedes deshabilitar, por eso no aparecer en el "screenshot" de arriba.

## Datos Empleados

Se puede reproducir lo anterior con `'datos_de_csv.csv'`:

```
SAP, sexo, edad
Buena salud, Mujer, 20
Mala salud, Hombre, 60
Buena salud, Hombre, 35
Mala salud, Hombre, 52
Buena salud, Mujer, 24
Mala salud, Mujer, 32
Buena salud, Mujer, 27
Mala salud, Hombre, 39
```

Si deseas saber cuál es la ruta configurada en tu ordenador (computadora) para `R` puedes usar `getwd()`